# my session destroy when paytm payment is completed in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, callback, logout, gateway, paytm

Everything is ok but when I make a payment on paytm payment gateway, so after success result, means when my order completed so callback automatically destroys my cart data and also makes the user logout. I don't where the problem is, so please can anyone help me with this. I think there is some problem in callback.

Comment: Pls. share your callback code

Answer (score 0):

You can either use "Cookies for cross-site usage must specify SameSite=None; Secure to enable inclusion in third party context" or "use our JS Checkout solution available on Paytm developer Portal".